# How can I find unused (CoffeeScript) classes in an AngularJS application?

Tags: coffeescript, webstorm

I am working on a angular js webapplication using coffeescript/github/webstorm. Because codebase is getting bigger I need a way of keeping the code clean. One of the things I would like to do is find unused coffeescript classes in my code. Is there any plugin/feature I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your github webhooks, you can call a script, to search in **/*.coffee: `class ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)`, then exclude from the matches: `extends ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)`, `new ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)`, `[\s=\:\{\(\[]([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\.`, etc. The remaining elements will be the likely unused classes. And you can send them in a e-mail.